# external swf control flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex4, swfloader

I have a flex application that loads an external swf file. I created the external swf file using flash cs4 so I can add code to it if that is what it takes.

Here is the code I use to load my external swf:

```
//add button swf
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.yadayada.com/media/but_button.swf");
var loader3:Loader = new Loader();
loader3.load(request);
addChild(loader3);
//position the ZoomControls

loader3.y = 0;
loader3.x = 0;
```

Can I have my external swf send click events to my flex application? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can do it.

```
function loadExternal():void {
  loader3.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
  loader3.load(request);
  addChild(loader3);
}
```

function onComplete(e:Event):void {
  var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target.content);
  mc.addEventListener(SomeEvent.EVENT_TYPE, onSomeEvent);
  mc.someExternalFunction();  //external function too can be called
}

You need to make External SWF in a way so that it allows cross scripting. So you need to put `Security.allowDomain("*"); // will make it's functions available to any swf loaded from any domain` inside external swf.

Comment: Fantastic Bhups! I got the button swf to load; however, I then ran into the problem of having my movieclips overlapping each other and screwing up my hitAreas. Spent all day and learned how to specify hitArea properties as well as draw VERY! complex shapes. Loving this language but I got a deadline to hit and I still cant figure out how to work a singleton class or sending events to other .as files.
Thanks again!!!

Comment: I didn't get your problem. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Now I'm trying to load an xml file but it is giving me security sandbox violations. How do I overcome these?